# Gridview Paging/Scrolling

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, scroll, paging

I have a Gridview with more rows than can be displayed on the screen without scrolling.
I added this to the page directive:

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

This works great when I click edit/update/delete on a particular row the page keeps the scroll position.

However, the Gridview also has paging enabled with multiple page links.
When I change pages the page keeps the scroll position at the bottom of the page.

I would like it to jump to the top of the page when switching between pages.
However, I still want it to maintain scroll position on row actions edit/update/delete described above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I put together:

In the .aspx file add:

```
<script>
    function ScrollToTop() {
        if (<%=(Scroll)%>) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<body onload="ScrollToTop()">
```

...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1 OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged"
```

...

---

In the code-behind .aspx.cs file added:

```
    protected string Scroll;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scroll = "false";
        Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scroll = "true";
    }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

This solution may work for you, found [here](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/dev-tutorials/overriding-maintainscrollpositiononpostback-with-gridview-pager-links/).  Basically you are handling the RowDataBound event to determine when the user has paged, if so, scroll to top.

**Javascript:**

```
// Scroll to the top of the Page
function ScrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, _
      ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)

  If e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.Pager) Then
  Dim pTableRow As TableRow = _
         CType(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0).Controls(0), TableRow)
  For Each cell As TableCell In pTableRow.Cells
    For Each control As Control In cell.Controls
      If TypeOf control Is LinkButton Then
        Dim lb As LinkButton = CType(control, LinkButton)
        lb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ScrollToTop();")
      End If
    Next
  Next
End If
End Sub
```

**My Attempt to convert to C#:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.Pager)) {
    TableRow pTableRow = (TableRow)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0].Controls[0];
    foreach (TableCell cell in pTableRow.Cells) {
        foreach (Control control in cell.Controls) {
            if (control is LinkButton) {
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)control;
                lb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ScrollToTop();");
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Javascript you provided was key to the solution.  See below.